# How wait() and notifyAll() prevents deadlock in given code snippet?

Tags: java, concurrency, wait, deadlock, notify

Here is the code snippet:

```
public class PrintEvenOdd 

  public static class SynchronizedThreadMonitor {
    public final static boolean ODD_TURN = true;
    public final static boolean EVEN_TURN = false;
    private boolean turn = ODD_TURN;

    public synchronized void waitTurn(boolean oldTurn) {
        while (turn != oldTurn) {
            try {
                wait();
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                System.out.println("InterruptedException in wait(): " + e);
            }
        }
    }

    public synchronized void toggleTurn(){
        turn ^= true;
        notify();
    }
}

public static class OddThread extends Thread {
    private final SynchronizedThreadMonitor monitor;

    public OddThread(SynchronizedThreadMonitor monitor) {
        this.monitor = monitor;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        for (int i=1; i<=100; i+=2) {
            monitor.waitTurn(SynchronizedThreadMonitor.ODD_TURN);
            System.out.println("i= " + i);
            monitor.toggleTurn();
        }
    }
}

public static class EvenThread extends Thread {
    private final SynchronizedThreadMonitor monitor;

    public EvenThread(SynchronizedThreadMonitor monitor) {
        this.monitor = monitor;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        for (int i=2; i<=100; i+=2) {
            monitor.waitTurn(SynchronizedThreadMonitor.EVEN_TURN);
            System.out.println("i= " + i);
            monitor.toggleTurn();
        }
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
    SynchronizedThreadMonitor monitor = new SynchronizedThreadMonitor();
    Thread t1 = new OddThread(monitor);
    Thread t2 = new EvenThread(monitor);
    t1.start();
    t2.start();
    t1.join();
    t2.join();
}
```

}

Using 2 threads to print numbers. One prints odd numbers and another prints even numbers.

In my understanding, both waitTurn and toggleTurn share the same LOCK of the instance. So if one holds the LOCK, the other method could not run. So if EvenThread first invokes waitTurn method and wait for the turn change, it holds the LOCK, then OddThread could not enter the toggleTurn method and set the turn. This should lead to a deadlock as per my understanding. But it did not happen.

Can someone please explain why the deadlock did not happen?

Comment: `OddThread could NOT enter the toggleTurn` No, `wait()` releases the lock and allows other threads to enter.  The lock is re-acquired before `wait()` returns.

Answer (score 0):

"So IF EvenThread first run waitTurn method and wait for the turn change, it holds the LOCK, the OddThread could NOT enter the toggleTurn method"

It holds the LOCK only small period of time, until method `wait()` is invoked. Method `wait()` releases the LOCK and allows another thread to enter the critical section.